# error: argument are required -i/--image

Tags: python-3.x, argparse, opencv3.0

> I wrote this code for shape detection but its showing error

```
# import the necessary packages
import shape_detector
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import sys

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i","--image", required=True,help="path to the input 
image",default = "~C:/Users/hp/Desktop/test2.png")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# load the image and resize it to a smaller factor so that
# the shapes can be approximated better
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
resized = imutils.resize(image, width=300)
ratio = image.shape[0] / float(resized.shape[0])

# convert the resized image to grayscale, blur it slightly,
# and threshold it
gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# find contours in the thresholded image and initialize the
# shape detector
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
sd = ShapeDetector()
# loop over the contours
```

after this part i used for loop on the conturs to detect the image
but it is showing this error

```
usage: working.py [-h] -i IMAGE
working.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image
```

> Please  tell me where to mention the path of my image and i am new to it so feel free to tell me where i am making mistake

Comment: How are you calling this code?  Do you know what `command line arguments` are?

Comment: @hpaulj i am new to it, i have put the whole code, please feel free to tell me the mistakes and if you can tell me the write way that will be great

Comment: We don't need the full code.  Do you understand the purpose of the argparse part?

Comment: it can be used to process the command line arguements when the program runs

Comment: From shell do: `$ python3 yourscript.py -i the_dir`. The error tells me you've omitted the `-i dir` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to provide the `-i` argument, remove the `required=True` from the following line:

```
ap.add_argument("-i","--image", required=True,help="path to the input 
image",default = "~C:/Users/hp/Desktop/test2.png")
```

This will cause the argument to be optional, and default to `"~C:/Users/hp/Desktop/test2.png"`.